# Arduino: Convert hex string to uint64 or decimal string

Tags: c, string, arduino, hex

I want to convert a hex string such as "43a2be2a42380" to their decimal representation using a uint64 variable. I need that because i'm implementing a RFID reader acting as a keyboard and the keypresses need to be the decimal digit.

I have seen other answers ([convert HEX string to Decimal in arduino](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31830143/convert-hex-string-to-decimal-in-arduino)) and implementing a solution using strtoul but it only works for 32 bit integers and strtoull is not available.

```
uint64_t res = 0;
String datatosend = String("43a2be2a42380");
char charBuf[datatosend.length() + 1];
datatosend.toCharArray(charBuf, datatosend.length() + 1) ;
res = strtoul(charBuf, NULL, 16);
```

What can i do to get the decimal number of a big hex string / byte array using an Arduino?

Comment: "decimal representation in a uint64 variable". Cognition circuit overload, contradiction in terms detected. It's either decimal representation, or a uint64 variable.

Comment: I said that because I need the real hexadecimal number not the decimal value of every digit!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can make your own implementation :

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <ctype.h>

uint64_t getUInt64fromHex(char const *str)
{
    uint64_t accumulator = 0;
    for (size_t i = 0 ; isxdigit((unsigned char)str[i]) ; ++i)
    {
        char c = str[i];
        accumulator *= 16;
        if (isdigit(c)) /* '0' .. '9'*/
            accumulator += c - '0';
        else if (isupper(c)) /* 'A' .. 'F'*/
            accumulator += c - 'A' + 10;
        else /* 'a' .. 'f'*/
            accumulator += c - 'a' + 10;

    }

    return accumulator;
}

int main(void)
{
    printf("%llu\n", (long long unsigned)getUInt64fromHex("43a2be2a42380"));
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Nitpicking: It should better be `getInt64fromHex(const char *str)`.

Comment: Yes, that is better ;)

Comment: And perhaps a `switch` ... `case` may be faster, instead of `if`s

Comment: Although may work fine with arduino, code would raise at least 5 issues on a code review.

Comment: 1) `"%llu\n"` match `unsigned long long`, not necessarily `uint64_t`.  <strike>2) `const` in signature</strike> (I had  old version) 3) `isxdigit(str[i])` is UB if `str[i]<0` (and not `EOF`),  4) strange to use `c >= 'A' && c <= 'F'` and not `isupper()`.  (also `c >= 'a' && c <= 'f'`)  5) Does not report errors. (overflow, bad character)6) Minor: `c - 'A' + 10` relies on typically character encoding.  OTOH) Good use of `size_t` although code could have simply used `str` and `str++`;

Comment: @chux This is an example, and I assumed the input was correct. OP will check the errors if he wants in his code. However : 1) On his 64 bits platform, `%llu` match `uint64_t`. 2) what do you mean ? the input is `const` in my function. 3) I will not implement another isxdigit since there is not the question here. I only provide an example. 4) I did not understand what you mean ? 5) Same answer as in 3. 6) I dare you to find a platform where ASCII code of A, B, C, D, E, F are not "contiguous".

Comment: @chux However, I recognize Alf's answer was better.

Comment: My initial comment began about working with arduino, the issues go beyond that platform.  1) %llu match `uint64_t` arduino today. Yet simple enough to use the portable C print specifier of `PRIu64` or cast operator to `unsigned long long`. 2) Your initial version lacked `const` and that what was on my screen.  the `< strike >` was to show my canceling of that issue.  3) Simple enough to use `isxdigit((unsigned char) str[i])` to avoid UB. 4) Code code could use `(isupper((unsigned char)c)` instead of `(c >= 'A' && c <= 'F')`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/109456/discussion-between-chux-and-morovaille).

Answer (score 6):

> ... solution using `strtoul` but it only works for 32 bit integers and `strtoull` is not available.

Do it twice using `strtoul()`, once for the lower four bytes, once for the rest and add the two results, multiplying the latter by `0x100000000LLU` beforehand.

Comment: That multiplication is not right. Besides, it would be clearer to use bit operators for this: `(uint64_t)upperPart << 32 | lowerPart`

Comment: @user694733: Thanks :}

Comment: Multipication is more error prone: It should be `0x100000000`.

Comment: @user694733: What appears to be "*clearer*" depends on the reader. The compiler does not care.

Comment: @user694733: Thanks^2; fixed!}

Comment: @user694733: Somewhat confused ... ;}}

Answer (score 0):

And more shorter convert:

```
void str2hex(uint8_t * dst, uint8_t * str, uint16_t len)
{
    uint8_t byte;
    while (len) {
        byte = *str-(uint8_t)0x30;
        if (byte > (uint8_t)0x9) byte -= (uint8_t)0x7;
        *dst = byte << 4;
        str++;
        byte = *str-(uint8_t)0x30; 
        if (byte > (uint8_t)0x9) byte -= (uint8_t)0x7;
        *dst |= byte;
        str++; dst++;
        len -= (uint16_t)0x1;
    }
}
```

And than for get uint64_t from unsigned char buffer:

```
uint64_t hex2_64(uint8_t * ptr)
{
    uint64_t ret;
    ret = (uint64_t)((uint64_t)(*ptr) << (uint64_t)56); ptr++;
    ret |= (uint64_t)((uint64_t)(*ptr) << (uint64_t)48); ptr++;
    ret |= (uint64_t)((uint64_t)(*ptr) << (uint64_t)40); ptr++;
    ret |= (uint64_t)((uint64_t)(*ptr) << (uint64_t)32); ptr++;
    ret |= (uint64_t)((uint64_t)(*ptr) << (uint64_t)24); ptr++;
    ret |= (uint64_t)((uint64_t)(*ptr) << (uint64_t)16); ptr++;
    ret |= (uint64_t)((uint64_t)(*ptr) << (uint64_t)8); ptr++;
    ret |= (uint64_t)(*ptr);
    return ret;
}
```

Comment: `str2hex()`? This would better be called `str2uint8()` wouldn't it?

Comment: And why pass a pointer to `hex2_64()` (which better would be called `uint8x8array2uint64())`?

Comment: str2hex / str2chr / str2u8, this and that (names and arguments) - depends on programmers team and project needs

Comment: `*ptr << 56` fails.  `*ptr` will be promoted to `int` and then shifted. If `int` smaller than 64 bit, the result is UB.  If `int` is 64-bit, the result is implementation defined.

Comment: Casts in `*str-(uint8_t)0x30;` and `byte > (uint8_t)0x9` serve no purpose.

Comment: @chux, I push casting everywhere and everytime - this is my paranoya =) I got infected by ST SPL sources reading.

Comment: You may like  `<stdint.h>. ... ret = *ptr * UINT64_C(1) << 56; ptr++;`