# How can I convert a string to uint16_t in Arduino?

Tags: string, arduino, uint16

The string variable will contain a hexadecimal, which we need to safely place in the `uint16_t`?

Example:

```cpp
String hexa = "0x11A0";
uint16_t num = ???;
```

Remember, I dont need to conversion to decimal here.
i.e. my requirement is, `unint16_t num = 0x11A0;`. I need to convert to an `unint16_t` from a hexadecimal.

`unint16_t` can contain `0x11A0`, but however my problem is that I cant get the value from a string variable and save it in `unint16_t`.

Comment: Arduino uses a dialect of C++. There are many examples on how to convert strings containing numbers into integer types if you just search a little.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31830143/convert-hex-string-to-decimal-in-arduino

Comment: Possible duplicate of [convert HEX string to Decimal in arduino](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31830143/convert-hex-string-to-decimal-in-arduino)

Comment: `String hexa = 0x11A0;` is not valid code. *error: no viable conversion from 'int' to 'String'*

Comment: String hexa = "0x11A0" ; I forgot the quotations.

Answer (score 0):

You want to convert a string containing a hexadecimal representation of an integer to an integer?

`strtol` can do that.

Remember, integers inside the Arduino are *binary* numbers. We care about binary, decimal, octal, and hexadecimal only when presenting values to humans. Most microprocessors operate on binary values.

So, include a file at the top of your script, and use the `strtol` function to convert the string to an integer. By using 0 for the *base* argument, it will handle decimal, octal, and hexadecimal formatted values.

```
#include <stdlib.h>
...
// we use .c_str() to access the underlying C string
int16_t x = strtol(hexa.c_str(), NULL, 0);
```

Comment: I understand what you are implying, but this is not helping to solve the problem. See when I do what you have suggested, the int16_t contains the long integer only, but however I want the hexadecimal itself to be placed in the int16_t. The reason why I am sure it is possible, is because I am able to save a hexadecimal to int16_t directly, that is int16_t = 0x11A0, but cant get a hexadecimal from string and save it to int16_t.

Answer (score 0):

```
 const short MaxSubs=10;
 uint16_t Subs[MaxSubs];

  String myStr=String(Node, HEX);
  short n=myStr.length();
  short k=n;
  while(n>0)
  {
    String sub=myStr.substring(k, n--);
    Subs[n]=strtol(sub.c_str(), NULL, 0); 
    delay(50);`
    printf_P(PSTR("%lu: Sub %h \n\r"), millis(), Subs[n]);
  }
```